# How to map matrix rownames from other file and re-write it on the same matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have very big matrix, and I want to map it's row names from other file.

Basically I have two files; ***File A***, which contains  *names* and it's *IDs*.
**File B** is the matrix and it's row names comes from names in file A.
what I need to do is that, I should read the *row names* of my matrix in **file B** and find it's associated **ID** in **file A** and replace the **row name** with found **ID** in matrix B.

would someone knows how to implement it in R ?

Here is the sturcture of my file:

File A:

```
        Names                                                          IDs



    unc.edu.3bdcdadf-67da-4a50-b311-81196c0c8362.1162097.rsem.genes.results   TCGA-B6-A0WW-01A-11R-A109-07
    unc.edu.3bdcdadf-67da-4a50-b311-81196c0c8362.1162128.rsem.genes.normalized_results    TCGA-B6-A0WW-01A-11R-A109-07
    unc.edu.3c1b6647-26bb-4110-aaea-f542024e8bf3.1989626.rsem.genes.results     TCGA-AQ-A54O-01A-11R-A266-07
```

and File B:

```
rownames(mymatirx)



       unc.edu.3bdcdadf-67da-4a50-b311-81196c0c8362.1162097.rsem.genes.results
      unc.edu.3c1b6647-26bb-4110-aaea-f542024e8bf3.1989626.rsem.genes.results
```

Expected output:

File B:

```
  >rownames(mymatirx)

    CGA-B6-A0WW-01A-11R
    TCGA-AQ-A54O-01A-11R
```

I just need to keep the ID with before the fifth **-**  and drop the rest, which for our case, matched IDs are :

```
 TCGA-B6-A0WW-01A-11R-A109-07
    TCGA-AQ-A54O-01A-11R-A266-07
```

and we just keep :

```
 TCGA-B6-A0WW-01A-11R
 TCGA-AQ-A54O-01A-11R
```

and drop

```
-A109-07
-A266-07
```

Comment: Have you attempted to use ```merge``` or another similar method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
rownames(A) <- A$Names
rownames(B) <- A[rownames(B)]$IDs
rownames(B) <- gsub("\\-[^-]+\\-[^-]+$","",rownames(B))
```

- The first line sets the row names of `A` to the values in `A$Names`.
  We need this for indexing.
- The second line uses the row names of `B` as index into `A`,
  replacing with the values in `A$IDs`
- The third line removes everything from the second-to-last `-` from
  the new row names in `B`